# Dropdown menu select does not work using C# selenium on Phantomjs

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, html-select

Does anyone know why Selenium can't see dropdown menu while using `phantom`, with `firefox` there is no errors.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='searchCompositeComponent:contentForm:searchParamPane:j_id_30:sortDropdown']")).Click();

Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@data-label='data']")).Click();
```

`Firefox` works fine, but `phantom` gives error on the second line, where it should select from dropdown

> error msg: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Also tried this:

```
IWebElement OPT = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='searchCompositeComponent:contentForm:searchParamPane:j_id_30:sortDropdown']"));

OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement selectTag = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(OPT);

selectTag.SelectByText("Data");
```

[image: https]

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are working with `<div>` element by provided id while you should work with `<select>` element using `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement()` as below :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

//implement WebDriverWait to wait until dropdown visible
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
IWebElement dropdown = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("searchCompositeComponent:contentForm:searchParamPane:j_id_30:sortDropdown_input")));

SelectElement selectTag = new SelectElement(dropdown);
selectTag.SelectByText("Enter dropdown visible option text here");
```

**Edited** :- If unfortunately Select element is not getting visible you can find existing select element and perform selection using `IJavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
IWebElement dropdown = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("searchCompositeComponent:contentForm:searchParamPane:j_id_30:sortDropdown_input")));

IJavascriptExecutor js = driver as IJavascriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", dropdown, "Enter dropdown visible option text here");
```

Comment: Thanks for info, but the thing is in web page select element is not visible, it is on top of dropdown menu, selenium could not find it again.

I thought about more simple solution. There are suggest in the dropdown menu, so i just selected input field, entered what i need and hit enter with Keys.Enter; But thanks for help :)

Comment: Just tried input and enter method, doesn't work. Your suggestion Saurabh seems to not work as it should, selenium in phantom could not find element after time out, element is not visible :/

Comment: @MilgerdasKaselis is this dropdown manually visible on the page??

Comment: Dropdown select is visible only by inspecting element in browser window

Comment: @MilgerdasKaselis Ok try then using IJavascriptExecutor..try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: Tried IJavaScript, doesn't seem to work too. I will use firefox, its way easier, colleague agreed with firefox usage. Thanks for help Saurabh, appreciated :)